how do I install sdkmanager?
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-11076708_latest.zip
I tried with the above mentioned link but I am unable to install sdk in my windows. Please help me to configure this. This will help me to automate the mobile applications. After configure this what else need to maintain in my windows to setup appium??

Have you executed sdkmanager as mentioned on the download page? https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools

It is not clear which problem you are facing. Could you please elaborate on which part of the installation you are facing the issue? What is the error or problem you are facing?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
